# Fix spacing of a chemfig in tabular environnement

Tags: tables, spacing, chemfig

I have a `tabular`containing several chemical formulas and unfortunately, even though the text is spaced correctly the molecules touch the border like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/t9SoMXw.png]

Code :

```
\subsubsection{Groupes}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Acides carboxyliques & \scalebox{.7}{\chemfig{R-C([1]=O)-[7]O-[8]H}} & - oique\\
\hline
Ester & \scalebox{.7}{\chemfig{R-C([1]=O)-[7]R'}} & R -oate de R' -yle
\end{tabular}
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the package [Booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) with it's own line system (\toprule \midrule \bottomrule) makes better spacing between the figures and the horizontal lines.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    Name & Molecule & Sufix \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(l){3-3}
    Acides carboxyliques & \scalebox{.7}{\chemfig{R-C([1]=O)-[7]O-[8]H}} & - oique\\
    \midrule
    Ester & \scalebox{.7}{\chemfig{R-C([1]=O)-[7]R'}} & R -oate de R' -yle\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

However the vertical lines are not advised with this package

[image: result]